# Instance of 'Button' has no 'bind' member and Instance of 'MyGrid' has no 'gondergitsin' member. Error

Tags: python, kivy

There is an error on line 61 in the code below.

he gives the error in his ***self*** words.

```
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Veritabanı adı: "))
        self.veritabaniadi = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.veritabaniadi)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Eklenecek verinin adı: "))
        self.eklenecekveri = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.eklenecekveri)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Eklenecek verinin içeriği: "))
        self.eklenecekvericerigi = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.eklenecekvericerigi)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.ekleonaylandi = Button(text="Veriyi Ekle")
        self.ekleonaylandi.bind(on_process=self.gondergitsin) """this line. here is the comment."""
        self.add_widget(self.ekleonaylandi)
```

what is the error and how can i solve it?

Comment: If you are binding `self.gondergitsin`, you must define a method `gondergitsin` in the `MyGrid` class.

Comment: @John Anderson how can I do it? I am encoding this library by default.

Comment: Please show the full traceback of your exception, we can't guess what's going wrong just from the exception text (especially when you seem to be implying two different errors).

Comment: @Blckknght 
Should I assign all the codes? Since I use translation, I cannot fully understand what he is saying.

Comment: Where is the `gondergitsin()` method defined? By the way, did you intend to bind to `on_press` rather than `on_process`?

Comment: just below `def gondergitsin(self, instance):
    dbadi = self.veritabaniadi.text
    eklenecekveri = self.eklenecekveri.text
    eklenecekvericerigi = self.eklenecekvericerigi.text

    duyuru = myclient["duyurular"]

    verri = duyuru[dbadi]

    verri.insert({
        eklenecekveri: eklenecekvericerigi
    })`

Comment: If that method definition does not appear within the `class MyGrid(GridLayout):`, then you cannot bind to it as you have attempted.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I applied the method you said. This time, on the same line, the place I highlighted in the self.**ekleonaylandi**.bind part gave an error.

Error: undefined variable. ekleonaylandi: button.

How can I figure it out?

Comment: Cannot tell from what you have posted. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @John Anderson I think you asked for the codes regularly.

[Here.](https://www.codepile.net/pile/pOpJP0BY)

Comment: Try changing `on_process` to `on_press`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson 
this time the error is in the word self. Sorry I'm doing a little bit of trouble. The error is on the same line and only in the initial self.

Comment: self: MyGrid
Instance of 'Button' has no 'bind' member

Comment: I downloaded your code from codepile and I cannot get that error. Your code works for me. Sorry I cannot help.

Comment: Okey, No problem. Thank you.